# UITableView with Realm backed db and online syncing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I need to implement a controller with UITableView that populates data from
a Realm and later another thread will sync the Realm's database with an online
web service. In other words I want to have a controller with the possibility
to work in offline mode.

I'm going to do it this way. Since it's my first experience with Realm and GCD,
I want to undertand if I am on a right way.

1. In my controller I'm going to have an instance var

   `var countries: Results<Country>!`
2. In the `viewDidLoad()` of the controller I will populate this ivar with data:

   ```
   countries = Realm().objects(Country)
   ```

The rest part is not written yet, so I will not supply code.

3. At the end of the `viewDidLoad()` I will `dispatch_async` a task for downloading
   the online data for my UITableView.
4. After the download is complete I will dispatch_sync a task on the **Main queue**
   which:

4.1. Will reassign the controller.countries and
4.2. Will call `controller.reloadData()` to reload the UITableView

Am I on a right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly correct. I have only a correction for your way.

> 4.1. Will reassign the controller.countries

`RLMResults` has features that everything is always up to date. The latest data will be reflected to `RLMResults` when you will commit the transaction adding to Realm downloaded data. So you do not require to reassign `controller.countries`. You can just call `controller.reloadData()` when the transaction is committed.

There is a little bit another way to use notifications. Realm instances send out notifications to other instances on other threads every time a write transaction is committed. If you registered notification block to your realm, you can reload the table view in the block.

See also `TableView` example code https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/objc/TableView
It shows how to use Realm with UITableView and background operation.

Comment: Thank you! BTW, your answer clarified the Realm's doc where its was said that the Results "is an auto-updating container type".

Comment: It is in the API document https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMResults.html. The doc says "RLMResults is an auto-updating container type in Realm returned from object queries."